# How to determine what value a reducer counts?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

after running a map I get

key, value
1,day,night,day
2,day,day

This values are passed to the reducer.
My reducer

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;

public class RTransactionPerPartOfDay implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> outputCollector, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        IntWritable intWritable = new IntWritable();
        int transactionPerPartOfDayCount = 0;
        while(values.hasNext()){
            transactionPerPartOfDayCount += 1;
            values.next();
        }
        intWritable.set(transactionPerPartOfDayCount);
        outputCollector.collect(key, intWritable);
    }
```

gives the following output

1,3
2,2

which means, we encounter key 1 3 times and key 2 2 times. What do I need to do make reducer count keys separatele based on the number of times we encounter a value?

like this

1,1
1,2
2,2

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is. Why would you have 1,1 and 1,2 in your output? The 1 key is "reduced" into a single output - what criteria would you have to split it after removing the time in the mapper?

Comment: Also, this output would be much easier with Spark, Hive, or Pig, so do you have to use Mapreduce?

Comment: What kind of map are we talking about? The key in a map has to be unique, so I have no idea how you can receive the same key twice with different values.

Comment: @Wes key is user id, value is time of day he logins. This are the values map passes to the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1

In map output make value as part of the key:

```
1 day, null
1 night, null
1 day, null
2 day, null
2 day, null
```

Then split it at reduce:

```
public class RTransactionPerPartOfDay implements Reducer<Text, NulLWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<NullWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> outputCollector, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String[] keyParts = key.toString().split(" ");
        int count = 0;
        for (NullWritable aValue : values) count++;
        outputCollector.collect(new Text(keyParts[0]), new IntWritable(count));
    }
```

### Solution #2

Use hashmap to count in reduce if it fits the memory limits.

Answer (score 0):

your key values in reducer are 1 and 2, when key is 1, values are {1,2} and when key is 2, values are {2}, so try something like this:

```
while(values.hasNext()){
      transactionPerPartOfDayCount += Integer.parseInt(values.next());
}
```